# shadowmapping and sampler2DShadow

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, shadow-mapping

I have been trying to implement shadowmapping in my terrain LOD program. I have spent quite some time researching different techniques and playing around with my code, but I just can't find my error, so it's time to ask the opengl gurus on stack overflow :)

I am using c++, opengl, GLFW3, GLM, GLEW, GLSL (430)

I have messed around with different ways of doing this, but the result is always one of the following:

1. Entire scene is rendered with visibility = 0.0;
2. Entire scene is rendered with visibility = 1.0;

////// project summary

[image: no shadows, diffuse lighting]

The terrain is built using quads that span from <0,0,0> to <2048, 400, 2048>, then tesselated by the tess control and evaluation shaders depending on charPos.

I use different *.cpp files to store render functions for different parts of the scene, so the vp_matrix variable gets computed in "main.cpp" and passed to every render function e.g. renderTerrain(vp_matrix). Then, I use mvp = vp_matrix * m depending on the case. For terrain, I use m to translate the vp_matrix by <-charPos.x, 0, -charPos.z> to center the map on the player before it is rendered to color. When I render to the depthBuffer for shadows, I do not use this translation. I render the entire scene as an ortho projection from the perspective of the sun with the bounds of my map (<0,0,0> to <2048, 400, 2048>).

I use static variables, because I reuse certain names in certain files. e.g. ProgramID, and I do not want them to overlap, so any variable that isn't defined in the "reduced" code is a static global to that file.

I should add that all shaders compile with no errors.

////// code

I did my best to reduce the code into only parts that effect shadowmapping.
The 2 files that are relevant are "main.cpp" and "terrain.cpp".

"main.cpp" has FBO initialization and the main rendering loop.
"terrain.cpp" contains most of the meat.

I didn't include boilerplate code e.g. generating the VAO.

*********** main.cpp ***********

*** init ***

```
ShadowFrameBufferID = 0;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &ShadowFrameBufferID);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, ShadowFrameBufferID);

glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, NULL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_BORDER);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL_LEQUAL);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);
glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE);
glReadBuffer(GL_NONE);

if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
    printf("shadow framebuffer error\n");
}
```

*** render loop ***

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, ShadowFrameBufferID);

glViewport(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

glm::mat4 depthProjectionMatrix = glm::ortho<float>(0.0f, 2048.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 0.0f, 2048.0f);
glm::mat4 depthViewMatrix = glm::lookAt(sunPos, glm::vec3(0), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
glm::mat4 depth_vp_matrix = depthProjectionMatrix * depthViewMatrix;

renderTerrainShadows(depth_vp_matrix);

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

glViewport(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

glClearColor(0.478f, 0.702f, 0.816f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

renderTerrain(vp_matrix, depth_vp_matrix, depthTexture);

glfwSwapBuffers(window);
glfwPollEvents();
```

*********** terrain.cpp ***********

*** shader source ***

```
// shadow/main vertex shaders (passthrough)
#version 430
layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;
out vec2 vposition;
void main()
{
    vposition = position;\n"
}

// shadow tess evaluation shader
#version 430
uniform mat4 shadowMVP;
void main()
{
    computeXYZ(); // world coordinates

    gl_Position = shadowMVP * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
}

// shadow fragment shader
#version 430
layout(location=0) out float fragmentDepth;
void main()
{
    fragmentDepth = gl_FragCoord.z;
}

// main tess evaluation shader
#version 430
uniform mat4 mvp, shadowBiasMVP;
out vec4 shadowPosition;
void main()
{
    computeXYZ(); // world coordinates

    gl_Position =    mvp * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
    shadowPosition = shadowBiasMVP * vec4(x, y, z, 1.0f);
}

// main fragment shader
#version 430
out vec3 color;
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMap;
in vec4 shadowPosition;
void main()
{
    color = doStuff(); // compute from diffuse / fog effect / etc

    float visibility = texture(shadowMap, vec3(shadowPosition.xy/shadowPosition.w, shadowPosition.z/shadowPosition.w));
    color = color * visibility;
}
```

*** init ***

```
// shadow program
ShadowProgramID = loadshaders4(shadow_vertex_shader_source, shadow_tessellation_control_shader_source, shadow_tessellation_evaluation_shader_source, shadow_fragment_shader_source);
ShadowMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(ShadowProgramID, "shadowMVP");

// main program
ProgramID = loadshaders4(vertex_shader_source, tessellation_control_shader_source, tessellation_evaluation_shader_source, fragment_shader_source);
ShadowMapID = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramID, "shadowMap");
MatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramID, "mvp");
ShadowBiasMatrixID = glGetUniformLocation(ProgramID, "shadowBiasMVP");
```

*** renderTerrainShadows ***

```
void renderTerrainShadows(glm::mat4 depth_vp_matrix)
{
    glUseProgram(ShadowProgramID);

    // uniforms
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ShadowMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &depth_vp_matrix[0][0]);

    // buffers
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 4);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_PATCHES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

*** renderTerrain ***

```
void renderTerrain(glm::mat4 vp_matrix, glm::mat4 depth_vp_matrix, GLuint depthTexture)
{
    glUseProgram(ProgramID);

    // uniforms
    // mvp matrix for rendering the scene needs to be translated to be centered on player
    glm::mat4 mvp = glm::translate(vp_matrix, glm::vec3(-charPos.x, 0.0f, -charPos.z));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &mvp[0][0]);

    // depth_mvp needs to be biased to change from [-1,1] to [0,1]
    glm::mat4 biasMatrix = glm::mat4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                     0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                                     0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                                     0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    glm::mat4 depth_mvp = biasMatrix * depth_vp_matrix;
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ShadowBiasMatrixID, 1, GL_FALSE, &depth_mvp[0][0]);

    // shadow texture (0)
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
    glUniform1i(ShadowMapID, 0);

    // buffers
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);

    glPatchParameteri(GL_PATCH_VERTICES, 4);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementbuffer);
    glDrawElements(GL_PATCHES, indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you for your help again! I've been stuck on that for a while. I guess I need to review the basics on the view and projection matrices before I move on! Do you program for EliteCAD?

Answer (score 0):

The sun position was too far away for the far plane given by `glm::ortho`